raster::sampleRamdom function take points where there are no values (generate NAs)
I'm trying to sample random points to use as background in a species distribution model. I'm using 30 second predictors from worldclim and soilgrids. The majority of the sampled random points are on the ocean, as if there were values in those cells, outside my masked area.
This is my code:
bg<-as.data.frame(sampleRandom(env.pred[[1]], size=10000, na.rm=F, xy=TRUE))`

env.pred is a rasterstack with all predictors masked:
> pred.mask
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 21600, 43200, 933120000, 24  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : r_tmp_2024-05-03_142200_7224_49931.grd 
names      :       bio1,      bio10,      bio11,      bio12,      bio13,      bio14,      bio15,      bio16,      bio17,      bio18,      bio19,       bio2,       bio3,       bio4,       bio5, ... 
min values :   9.283334,  11.466667,   6.466667, 502.000000,  58.000000,   0.000000,   5.105296, 157.000000,   1.000000,  79.000000,   1.000000,   5.566667,  36.323528,  86.614578,  16.600000, ... 
max values :   26.15417,   27.68333,   24.81667, 3249.00000,  403.00000,  163.00000,  103.06243, 1157.00000,  549.00000, 1157.00000,  841.00000,   14.12500,   78.41881,  465.92282,   33.30000, ... `

When I try na.rm=T I only get 61 points.
Has anyone experienced this situation?
My expectation was that all the sampled points would be inside my mask area.

I think you're getting far fewer values with na.rm because it's removing NA values after they're sampled, rather than not sampling NA values in your raster in the first place. I would assume that the sampling is taking place across the rectangular extent of the raster, so your mask isn't working as expected at this step.
Try using the ext argument in sampleRandom to limit the area (mask) for which sampling is done.
